# Yii Route failure

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting

I'm working on a Website and I installed the Rights Module (https://code.google.com/p/yii-rights/)

and in my localhost works fine but when I upload the site to the hosting it says:

"Unable to resolve the request "rights/authItem/tasks"."

This is my urlManager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            array(
                'class' => 'application.components.CategoriesRule',
                'connectionID' => 'db',
            ),
                array(
                        'class' => 'application.components.SinglePropertiesRule',
                        'connectionID' => 'db',
                    ),
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have routing problems only on the server, it usually means your  apache configuration is not configured with the correct rewrite instructions, did you check them?

Comment: In addition to @Manquer's comment, Is mod-rewrite enabled at your server?

Comment: I haven't check them, and that's a good point, because I had to make a rewrite rule (with no-experience), so it may be the reason of the problem. I'll give it a check.